# Get font size after applying adjustsFontSizeToFit in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using adjustsFontSizeToFit in a Text component, and I want to be able to set a variable to the font size that it adjusts the text to. How can I do this?

```
const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(0);
return (
   <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text numberOfLines={1} adjustFontSizeToFit>{text1}</Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={fontSize: fontSize}>{text2}</Text>
   </>
)
```

The fontSize of `text1` is dynamic because of adjustFontSizeToFit and is based on the size of its container. I want `text2` to then get set to whatever size text1 gets rendered as. Is there a method I can use to find out the fontSize that `text1` renders as, so that I then use `setFontSize` to make `text2` render at that same size?

(I'm thinking something equivalent to how I can use onLayout to get the dimensions of a component when it renders maybe?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please share your exact code example? This makes it easier to help instead of writing your entire code.

Comment: just added a code example!

Comment: I know this is resurrecting years old demons, but did you ever find an answer to this? Running into an issue where I need this as well. I know onTextLayout has some info in there, but none are font size.